# Starting With REPORTS in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report, visual-studio-express

I have a project to build statistical reports. i am told to use crystal reports if its a license free, If it is not than user some other free source.

This is my first attempt to use reports in asp.net. Can anyone guide me how to start with e.g if i am using crystal reports than how do i add a crystal report control in my toolbox(Microsoft Visual Developer Express Edition 2008).

Please help me to understand how reports work.Any good tutorials,from scratch would be very helpful.

Comment: express addition doesn't support crystal report

Comment: @ Emaad Ali >What is the other preferred solution

Comment: I use zedgraphs in express.  Its free.  Here is a tutorial link if you want to try it out, I got it up and running within 5 mins.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Reports are quite simple. I use the visual studio in built ones. I also create a data object to use as a dataset however, if you want you can use another dataset. Then it is a case of adding a report to your project (a .rdlc file) and setting it up using the items on the toolbox. I even think it comes with a wizard to help you with the dataset.

When you have done that just drop it on to a page. Of course. In .net 4 you now have the chart control. I haven't used that but it sounds quite good. There is a good video [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet-4/videos/aspnet-4-quick-hit-chart-control) that describes this control.

i don't know if [this link](http://www.asp.net/sql-server/videos/getting-started-with-reporting-services) is maybe what you are looking for either

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio express, since crystal reports are not available, I use zedgraphs. Its free. Here is a tutorial link if you want to try it out, goes through from start to finish how to include the DLL to use their libraries, initialize the co-ordinates, and display the type of graph.  I got it up and running within 5 mins.  Although I could see this getting a little slow if you are trying to chart millions of records, I use this on smaller datasets.

codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx